# Tableau: The barc chart doubles it height with null values when I add color

Tags: graph, visualization, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

[Screenshot of the bargraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9tIv.png)

I want to remove the yellow part that came from nowhere.

[It says the yellow are null values but idk where they came from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5yog.png)

This is my workbook: https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/kamalesh.ponnivalavan/viz/helpme/Sheet1?publish=yes

Answer (score 0):

Notice that all the yellow colour values are exactly the same as the totals in the bar graph values below the yellow values.

You can eliminate the yellow simply by right clicking in the yellow colour in the colour legend and excluding the null values.

But I suspect the underlying data is where the problem starts. But the colour value is clearly calculated in some way before the data is imported into Tableau. None of the colour values in the table have non-null incident IDs, so I suspect you have done some aggregation and the presence of null values is a side-effect of that calculation. You should probably fix this as it will be easier to analyse the result in tableau if you do.